# Outputting to External Display Only: ATI Radeon HD6310 Driver Issues on a Thinkpad x120e

Tags: 11.10, ati, display, hdmi, radeon

The *open driver* applied in Ubuntu 11.10 by default for **ATI's Radeon HD 6310** works fairly well. It detects my secondary display, the resolutions for both it and built in display [Thinkpad x120e], and maps them fairly well with limited overlap.

Users, however, are given two options from the 'Additional Drivers' dialogue:

- ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates)
- ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver

The former cannot be installed. The latter can, but once installed garbles bootscreen dimensions, and no longer detects displays. When implemented with Gnome-Shell rather than Unity, titlebar colors are distorted, and Gnome-Shell glitches between it and the underlying "fallback" environment, live.

Removal of the proprietary driver causes complete removal of Gnome-Shell and corruption of Unity and Unity-2D. Gnome-fallback works in limited capacity.

The third party driver from ATI's web page, installed with default options, does not seem to work.

All I really want to do is output to external display only. Which driver I use doesn't matter, although the Catalyst stuff would probably be best for the promise of increased performance. Any thoughts/feedback?

Comment: I am having the same problem I just got the Update done, I un-installed ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver to try and do the updated one. Well the ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (post-release updates) would not install, so I rebooted now I can not get back into the OS. How do I reinstall the display driver or boot 11.10 with limited graphics so I can reinstall the ATI driver?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the instructions highlighted in: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver to remove the installed proprietary flgrx driver with great success.